# Is there an IPS Blog, could we get one?

Tags: discussion

I don't think there is an IPS Blog. If there is please would you link it?

I think that our site could get more traffic if we had a blog. We would have to define exactly its contents, but we could use it to discuss different things IPS.

For example why some questions are put on hold and suggesting ways they could be improved so they could become valid questions.

We could also use it to talk about issues that have been asked in several questions and summarize different answers in a general good advice page.

Basically we could use it to go deeper in certain things we cannot right now because of the platform limitations. What do you think?

Also I am not sure how much work would it represent and who would have to write the blog. It seems like in ServerFault they have some associates that write blog entries.

**Some SE background:**

There was a Post on Meta about making [SO as a Blog platform](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83959/so-as-a-blog-platform).
There are some blogs live already:

- [Server Fault's Blog](https://blog.serverfault.com/)
- [Super User's Blog](https://blog.superuser.com/)

Comment: You mention SO and SU having their own blog but both those sites have graduated... I can't say whether having a blog would be a good idea but it seems a bit early to consider it given that IPS is still in beta.

Comment: Does the blog you think of an internal one (run by SOinc) or external (easy to set up, but *legal*?)? And who would put content in it, write articles?

Comment: @avazula if a blog would drive more traffic that seems like a good step towards graduation.  Otherwise it's a catch-22: we'll wait till we graduate to do the things that would help graduation.

Comment: This question made me curious, so [here's a list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339115/401104) of all the different site blogs I could find :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but I believe this is no longer possible (through Stack Exchange, at least).

The Meta.SE post [We're no longer starting new individual site Community Blogs - here's why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244467/were-no-longer-starting-new-individual-site-community-blogs-heres-why) is where blogs started stopping.  Then came...

> We are discontinuing Blog Overflow as a service on this network. Not only does this mean that no new blogs will be created, but it will also mean that all extant blogs are becoming functionally shut down.
>   <sub>[We will no longer be hosting Blog Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291741/we-will-no-longer-be-hosting-blog-overflow), Meta.SE, 2017</sub>

But I wouldn't be too upset about this; blogs distract users from the main site.

Comment: I think a properly driven blog could be very useful and engaging, however the point is moot since as you found out those are no longer possible. Thanks a lot for finding this!

Answer (score 0):

Right now, there isn't an IPS blog. Technically, we *could* get one. Blogs aren't only for graduated SE sites (in fact, I don't think graduation means we get a blog automatically), so another site, [astronomy](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/460/21719) has set up / is setting up their own unofficial blog.

But there's some work to be done before we can have one. Some of those things you already touch in your question: We need to find topics to write about. I'm not that fond of the two things you mention in your question though. I'd like the moderation of questions to stick to IPS main and meta. A blog is going to be harder to find, so I'm not fond of burying any information in there.

Combining questions and answers from on here into one big general good advice post might give newer visitors a 'wrong' idea of what our site is about, the impression that these very broad, generic good advice questions might be helpful.

Then again, I'm not sure what we'd put on a blog, besides 'generic good advice'. We could do [academic-research](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academic-research) like subjects, with literature reviews or something... but why put those on a blog, if they can also be on IPS main?

Also, we need people who want to write those blog posts. Take a look at the answers to this [astronomy meta question](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/470/21719): People can tell what they can write about, and how often they can write. I'm wondering if we have people on here that can tell us what they want to write about, if there was a blog?

Comment: You are right, from what I gather graduating doesn't mean you have a blog. The two subjects I suggested were just from the top of my head. I think is a good idea to figure out who may want to write and about what topics. Or we could even suggest possible topics. I was just thinking of ways we could give more exposure to the site. SOme people may not want to ask anything, but maybe they would enjoy reading on topics reated to IPS.

Comment: While I agree that we might be a bit too nascent for an IPS blog, the idea does intrigue me. A few topics that I can think of off the top of my head would be 1) having someone who asked a question and got an answer write a post explaining what their problem was and how IPS helped them solve it. 2) Spotlighting great answers